# Function expressions on global scope

Tags: javascript, function, class, typescript

After discovering TypeScript I've played around with the online compiler and the resulting JavaScript code made me wonder about function expressions.

A simple TypeScript class:

```
class Person {
    firstName: String = "John";
    lastName: String = "Doe";
}
```

Results in the following JavaScript code:

```
var Person = (function () {
    function Person() {
        this.firstName = "John";
        this.lastName = "Doe";
    }
    return Person;
})();
```

That made me wonder why they chose to go with self-executing function, when something simpler might have sufficed. What is the purpose of an inner function with a name identical to the variable?
And why didn't they go with something simpler, such as:

```
var Person = function() {
    this.firstName = "John";
    this.lastName = "Doe";
};
```

Or even:

```
function Person() {
    this.firstName = "John";
    this.lastName = "Doe";
}
```

As far as I can tell using function expressions on a global scope offers no advantages, only the disadvantage of not being able to call the function before it was declared.

Comment: I quickly played around and couldn't find any valid reason. Even for private static variables they aren't making use of their module scope since privates are enforced at compiling time only.

Comment: It's simply a deficiency of the compiler. Classes will always compile to IEFEs, as that "module" pattern helps with organisation of the class construction code and allows static (class-wide scoped, "private") variables. They forgot to unwrap the IEFE when they don't need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps with inheritance. It allows them to capture the base class with a rename to `_super` which helps with code generation e.g.:

```
class Foo{

}

class Bar extends Foo{

}
```

becomes :

```
var __extends = this.__extends || function (d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    __.prototype = b.prototype;
    d.prototype = new __();
};
var Foo = (function () {
    function Foo() {
    }
    return Foo;
})();

var Bar = (function (_super) {
    __extends(Bar, _super);
    function Bar() {
        _super.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    return Bar;
})(Foo); // Notice base class is captured here
```

This is good practice in JS as well. For example, if you kept using `Foo` in this example instead of `_super` and you were to change the base class you would have a whole avenue of headaches which can be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

You really don't want to be able to invoke a class before its declaration has executed. Consider this code:

```
class Person {
    static nameSeparator = ' ';

    public fullName: string;

    constructor(public firstName, public lastName) {
        this.fullName = firstName + Person.nameSeparator + lastName;
    }
}
```

And its generated form:

```
var Person = (function () {
    function Person(firstName, lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.fullName = firstName + Person.nameSeparator + lastName;
    }
    Person.nameSeparator = ' '; // <-- Important!
    return Person;
})();
```

Do you want code that accidently runs before the indicated line to run with undefined behavior (in this case, Person.fullName is "JohnundefinedSmith"), or just fail?

In other cases, the class simply won't work at all:

```
class Person {
    constructor(public firstName, public lastName) {
        // Will fail until Person.prototype.getFullName gets set
        console.log('New person, name = ' + this.getFullName());
    }

    getFullName() {
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does it have to be defined as `Person.nameSeparator`?

Comment: As opposed to declaring static variables as defined in my answer.

Comment: How is a derived class (or anyone else for that matter) supposed to access them?

Comment: Via getter and setter methods @Ryan

Comment: If that's what you want to do, make it private (or a non-exported member of a module if you want closure privacy) and write the getters and setters. Otherwise I've seen no feedback asking for TS to require writing a bunch of boilerplate to expose statics.

Comment: Your argument doesnt have much value. IIFE or not, the code runs sequentially and is generated by TypeScript. Try to declare a private static variable that instanciate the class at the top of the class definition and you will see that it will be put at the end.

Answer (score -1):

This allows for you to make some private variables.

In JS:

```
var Person = (function () {
    var firstName, lastName; //static private vars
    function Person(fName, lName) {
        firstName = fName;
        lastName = lName;
    }
    return Person;
})();
```

Comment: You can also do that in the other options I've presented.

Comment: These would be shared between all instances. Very bad example.

Comment: @Acidic in your examples first and last names are **not** private and can be accessed from the outside.

Comment: @qwertynl That's true, but if I declare them with the var keyword they will be private.

Comment: @Acidic yep. They would be private static vars. In your last 2 examples you cannot make any private static functions or variables

Comment: @qwertynl Interesting. I didn't really think of static variables when I asked the question, and the inner function dealing with implementation does seem to allow just that.